# how to use multilevel inheritance in Twig templates?

Tags: html, templates, symfony

Suppose i have three files .... file1.html.twig,  file2.html.twig  and  file3.html.twig

file1.html.twig contains some code blocks. I extend this template in file2.html.twig and file2.html.twig is extended further in file3.html.twig. so, will i be able to access the code blocks of template file1.html.twig in file3.html.twig ? if no, please suggest the other some other way, i am really stuck.

file2.html.twig extends file1.html.twig.

```
{# file2.html.twig #}
 {% extends 'Bundle_name:file1.html.twig'%}
```

and file3.html.twig extends file2.html.twig

```
{# file3.html.twig #}
 {% extends 'Bundle_name:file2.html.twig'%}
```

Comment: yes you'll be able to access blocks defined in file1 from file3

Comment: yes, as ponciste says. Moreover, a quick try should've helped you in the same amount of time that you used to wrote that question, I can bet on in :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rendered twig template file3 will contain file1 template with overridden blocks by file2 and file3.

Comment: thanks for the help. I can really move on now.    Just wondering, can it be done with 'include' keyword as well...?